# python variability in function definition

Tags: python, function, variables, lambda, arguments

I'm trying to write a single function that simplifies/combines these functions:

```
def func0(x, a0):
    return a0

def func1(x, a0, a1):
    return a0 + a1*x

def func2(x, a0, a1, a2):
    return a0 + a1*x + a2*x**2

def func3(x, a0, a1, a2, a3):
    return a0 + a1*x + a2*x**2 + a3*x**3
```

into a function like this:

```
def func[n](x,a0,a1,...,an):
    return a0*x**0 + a1*x**1 + a2*x**2 + ... + an*x**n
```

The purpose for this is to be used with scipy.optimize.curve_fit which requires a callable function where the number of arguments is used as the number of parameters to optimize for.

For example:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from numpy import *

def func[n](x, *list( vars()['a'+str(i)]      for i in range(0, n+1) ) ):
    return       sum( vars()['a'+str(i)]*x**i for i in range(0, n+1) )

xdata = array([1,2,3,4])
ydata = array([0.012,1.456,4.673,8.927])

popt,pcov = curve_fit(func[2],xdata,ydata)

plot(xdata, ydata, 'o')
plot(arange(0,5,.1), func[2](arange(0,5,.1),*popt))
show()
```

If the extremely odd definition of func[n] makes sense

I'm guessing that with some creativity and the use of lambda this is possible but I've been unable to figure it out... I hope it's possible.

Thanks in advance for the help :)

PS. Any idea how to color-code the coding for ease of readability?

Answer (score 3):

```
def func(x, *args):
    return sum(arg*x**n for n, arg in enumerate(args))
```

Comment: thanks for showing me the sum function Jared :-)
unfortunately though  this fails at the line:
    popt,pcov = curve_fit(func,xdata,ydata)
because its unspecified how many arguments that curve_fit will ask for

Comment: You can prevent sicpy from trying to determine the number of parameters your function has by passing the `p0` argument.